# Easy Auto Complete, referencing deeply nested values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm working with a neat auto-complete program called "[Easy Auto Complete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-providers)".

The program works great, however I'm stumped on how to reference deeply nested node sets. The javascript running the show uses an attribute labelled "listlocation" that pulls values nested beyond the root of the JSON feed.

However, when attempting to pull data (ID for example) from the "player" data set, I have no success (developer tools tell me I'm not receiving data). I've tried "player", "playerstatsentry.player", "cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry" and other variations of.

When I use a JSON feed where values reside on the root or ONE level up (as per [the documentation](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-providers)), the feature works great.

What is the best way to reference the player array to pull the ID value?

JSON

```
{
"cumulativeplayerstats": {
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2018-02-13 1:59:59 PM",
    "playerstatsentry": 
        [
            { "player": { "ID": "5107" } }
            ....
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var options = {
    url: "assets/data.json",
    listLocation: "cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry.player",
    getValue: "LastName"
    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};
$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Comment: In the `Javascript` you have written code for `LastName` and question is regarding the `ID` selection. Anyways, I wrote the answer for `LastName` selection, you can do the same for `ID` property too. Hope it helps!!

Comment: if the answer was helpful, you can accept it by voting up. Otherwise let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin expects a collection of `object`s and a `property` name which will be used as a autocomplete help. You need to restructure the `data.json` file logically:

**Case 1:** When `JSON` structure is as

```
{
   "cumulativeplayerstats": {
      "lastUpdatedOn": "2018-02-13 1:59:59 PM",
      "playerstatsentry": [
         {
            "player": {
               "ID": "5106"
            },
            "LastName": "Test 1"
         },
         {
            "player": {
               "ID": "5107"
            },
            "LastName": "Test 2"
         },
         {
            "player": {
               "ID": "5108"
            },
            "LastName": "Test 3"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Than use autocomplete configuration as:

```
<input id="provider-json" />
<script>
var options = {
    url: "assets/data.json",
    listLocation: function(data) {
        return data.cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry;
    },
    getValue: "LastName",
    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};
$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

**Case 2:** Because `getValue` property also supports function in this plugin. If the `JSON` structure is as:

```
{
   "cumulativeplayerstats": {
      "lastUpdatedOn": "2018-02-13 1:59:59 PM",
      "playerstatsentry": [
         {
            "player": {
               "ID": "5106",
               "LastName": "Test 1"
            }
         },
         {
            "player": {
               "ID": "5107",
               "LastName": "Test 2"
            }
         },
         {
            "player": {
               "ID": "5108",
               "LastName": "Test 3"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

use the autocomplete code as:

```
var options = {
    url: "assets/data.json",
    listLocation: function(data) {
        return data.cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry;
    },
    getValue: function(item) {
        return item.player.LastName;
    },
    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};
$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Hope this helps!!